# Objective C-How to rotate an UIImageView over another UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, imageview

I am trying to create a Hygrometer. I have an image of Hygrometer and an image of a needle (rotateimg). I need to show the readings on the meter by pointing the needle to the reading value. It should rotate on a point ie, the center of the hygrometer image

I tried this code.

```
[[rotateimg layer]setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5,0.25)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 animations:^{
        [rotateimg setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*r/180.0)];
    }];
```

but this doesnot work.Here 'r' is the reading value

[image]

this is the output I am getting. It rotates the image but not on a center point.

How to solve this issue please help

Comment: Rotation occurs about the point 0, 0, so your transform needs to offset to the middle, then rotate, then offset back.

Comment: @DavidBerry Can you provide me an example please..

Comment: @iPeter  hygrometer reading that the needle should point to